# Is it possible for Models to know which tenant is using it?

Tags: django, multi-tenant

I'm offering a SaaS, mostly as a django dashboard and customized admin panel. Using tenants I have one schema per customer sharing a database. The problem I have is that the customer should be able to create objects through the admin page and the objects should create an url with information about the tenant. For example customer Y's url would be Y.xzxzxz.com and customer X's url would be X.xzxzxz.com. There will be multiple types of urls with the same prefix. Currently I the customers have to manually input the customer prefix. Is it possible for the Models class to know which schema is using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported Connection from django.db and then used connection.get_tenant().name and I got what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not at all clear what you're asking. But I'm taking a guess that you want to know which of multiple databases a model exists in.

Your `settings.py` will likely have `DATABASE` keys like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': 'postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/default',
    'tenant_1': 'postgres://user:pass@localhost:5432/tenant_1',
}
```

So once you've saved a model you can ascertain which database it exists in by doing:

```
instance = YourModel.objects.create()
print(instance._state.db)
# Prints "default" or "tenant_1" depending on which database its in
```

[relevant docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading)

Comment: This is the "template" I've followed for creating the system: https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants so I've set up the tenant through the terminal. The url is basically self.slug = (self.customerPrefix + ".....local...." + ....") and I get the customerPrefix because right now I'm inputting it manually. I was thinking about reading the prefix from the admin url if I don't figure out another way.

Comment: @JohnDoe, most SO folks have a full time job on top of their OSS and other activities. Nobody's going to crawl around in your repo debugging it for you. I suggest you read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ...and also put a minimal reproducible example in the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I didn't mean for you to think I wanted someone to read through those it's just that there is a short section on the database as to show I've set it up in a different way. But none of this is even necessary I just asked a question that isn't necessarily tied to any debugging or actual code. I didn't expect more than "no because x" or "yes I've done y"